# UITableView Crashes on Fast Scroll

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nsmanagedobject

I have a TableView that populates data fetched from a NSFetchedResultsController.  However, the app just stops responding when the user scrolls too fast in the Table view (usually around the bottom of the Table).

Xcode displays a crash- breakpoint in the

`- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

at the line where i assign the cell attributes:

cell.name.text = [Person firstName:speaker.firstName andLastName:speaker.lastName]; 
(cell is a PersonStyleCell, subclass of UITableViewCell).

**EDIT**

Fooling around with the NSManagedObject's faulting state property, i'm now getting  the error:

```
CoreData could not fulfill a fault for '0x37f8f0
```

Again, the App only crashes when the user scrolls the UITableView too fast.

Any idea why the app crashes? There's no memory leaks, and im only releasing the NSFetchedResultsController Objects in the dealloc method.  What could be the issue?

I Realized that:

```
 ([(Person*)[self.personArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] faultingState] == 0)
```

will check if the data stored in the NSManagedObject is faulting (i.e. isn't 'loaded' yet), and I think the problem is that it's trying to set the cell attributes with data that isnt accessible yet.

Placing the "set cell attributes" functions in an if statement  that only proceeds to set the cell attributes if the data is not faulting seems to fix the crash, but no data is displayed (i guess when it is initialized, the data for all the objects is set as "fault"

Can I use this faulting status property to wait till the data is has loaded before setting the cell attributes?  If so, how?

Im hoping this information will have simplified my question considerably

Comment: yeah, i believe the `UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:PlaceholderCellIdentifier];` takes care of that

Comment: Are you getting the data for each Person in the Person array from some REST API - is that why it's taking time to come back?

Comment: nope- data is being retrieved from CoreData

Comment: managed to get the new error - see revised question

Comment: Hard to debug with the information here but it seems like CoreData may have some corrupted data in it? Try setting a breakpoint on the error to see which CoreData object is causing this.

Comment: the data isn't corrupted.. when you scroll fast, the data stored for the entry that's trying to be populated is stored as <fault> meaning i can't access the 'Person' object thats stored for the indexpath for the cell...even though its there.  When the user scrolls slowly, it has enough time to load the Person object into that entry.  

take a look at this: [link](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdFaultingUniquing.html)

Answer (score 2):

What batch size were you setting? I had this problem with a large number of lightweight objects using a batch size of 20. Increasing the batch size (for me it was 60) prevented the crash without any adverse effects on scrolling performance.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a CoreData expert but I don't think speed is the issue (we use CoreData in our app and I can't out-scroll it).

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdTroubleshooting.html suggests that you're deleting objects. Are you trying to use CoreData with multiple threads (always tricky)?

If faultingState "works" it's because you're not going to be fully initialized if there's an error.